# HP Tuning with keras model and setting hyperparameterMetric to a Evaluation Metric and not training metric

Tags: keras, google-cloud-platform

It is about Hyperparameter Tuning with GCP.
With estimators I can easily set the desired hyperparameterMetric to the proper metric on evaluation data. But I don't see how I can do that for a keras (tf.keras and keras) model?

I mean where can I "assign" the right metric? I need the hyperparameterMetric to be the metric for evaluation data.

Edit:

model.fit returns a dict like:

```
{'acc': [0.9843952109499714],
 'loss': [0.050826362343496051],
 'val_acc': [0.98403786838658314],
 'val_loss': [0.0502210383056177]
}
```

Does GCP works now if I just set my desired validation metric to 'val_acc' in the config file without doing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

1. you must use keras callback of tensorboard
2. use prefix "epoch_" for ParameterMetricTag=epoch_val_acc for validation accuracy and ParameterMetricTag=epoch_acc for training accuracy